# Collapsed sidenav in angular 2 with material 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm developing sidenav using Angular 2 and Material 2,

In **Open State**, it looks like below,

[image]

But on **Close state** it hides the whole sidenav, instead I want to hide only the menu text and not the icon.

Look at my code,

```html
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <button md-icon-button (click)="start.toggle()">
        <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>Test Project
  <button md-icon-button (click)="logout()">
      <md-icon>exit_to_app</md-icon>
    </button>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-layout class="left-navigation">
  <md-sidenav #start mode="side" opened="true">
    <md-nav-list>
      <a [routerLink]="view.link" md-list-item *ngFor="let view of views" (click)="sidenav.close()">
        <md-icon md-list-icon>{{view.icon}}</md-icon>
        <span md-line>{{view.name}}</span>
      </a>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
  <div class="demo-sidenav-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same task and that is how I solve it:

```
md-sidenav-container {
  min-width: 60px;
}

md-sidenav {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

md-sidenav.mat-sidenav-closed {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

UPDATE: Solution above has a side effect - navbar never reaches states "opened" and "closed" if triggered at least once. It has intermediate states "opening" and "closing".

To make it work and have animations completed, I used more hacky solutions:

```
md-sidenav-container {
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 60px;
}

md-sidenav {
  width: 230px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.mat-sidenav-closed md-nav-list,
.mat-sidenav-closing md-nav-list {
  margin-left: 230px;
  width: 230px;
  visibility: visible;
 }

:host >>> .mat-sidenav-focus-trap>.cdk-focus-trap-content {
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

The only difference in appearance is animations behavior. But as for me it's even nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the plunker example I have linked in this git issue here: [click](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2021)

It's similar to what you need, but the icons are on the other side of the sidenav, thus you would need more animation in order to keep with that structure.

But I'm pretty sure this will give you a good idea how to collapse the sidenav, leaving a portion of it still visible.